# How to fix rubocop offense for a class class a::b::c

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, module, rubocop

I have following file
lib/a/b/c.rb

```
class a::b::c
  def request(env)
    #some code here
  end
end
```

Now i am using rubocop style

```
Style/ClassAndModuleChildren:
  Enabled: true
```

I am getting rubocop offense for this

```
lib/a/b/c.rb:1:7: C: Use nested module/class definitions instead of compact style.
class a::b::c
```

When i update my code to following offence get fixed

Style 1

```
class a
  class b
    class c
      def request(env)
        #some code here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Style 2

```
module a
  module b
    class c
      def request(env)
        #some code here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I think i should use `Style 2` as i am using `require 'a'` in one of my file.

Please let me know how to fix this type & offences and reason for it

Answer (score 10):

The reason this is marked as offence is that constants resolution works lexically, rather than semantically in ruby. This is not intuitive and might lead to some obscure errors (for example if you have two classes with the same name in two different scopes). Compare these two cases:

```
# Given
module Foo
  X = 42
end

# This
module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      puts X
    end
  end
end

# VS
class Foo::Bar
  def baz
    puts X
  end
end
```

Now when you call:

```
Foo::Bar.new.baz
```

In the first case you will get `42`, in the second - `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::X`

---

As for which is the correct way to fix it: Note that using the short syntax will give you an error if `Foo` doesn't already exist. The answer is - you should use whatever `Foo` is. If it's a class - use `class`, if it's a module - `module`.

Answer (score 4):

[`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Class.html) class is essentially derived from `Module` class, that’s why `Class` is a `Module` with some added functionality; basically the difference is in that `Class`es might be instantiated.

So, the answer to your question would be: use whatever is more suitable in your case (and by the information given it is impossible to say, what it is.)

`require 'a'` has nothing to do with the case, since `require` directive just forces ruby interpreter to *load* the respective code.

*NB:* that kind of question is the exact reason why Rubocop complains: it prevents you from using something you are not certain about and forces you to understand, is it in fact `Module`, or `Class` by it’s nature.

BTW, since you mentioned you have `require 'a'` somewhere, it probably means that in this `a.rb` you have already either `module A` or `class A`.

BTW#2 Both class and module names must begin with capital letter, because they are to be *constants*.